# how can i display a list of roles in Razor Pages view?

Tags: c#, razor-pages, selectlist

I am trying to add a list of the roles in my asp.net core web application to a Razor Page but I'm not sure how to do this. I want the user to be able to choose what role a new user being registered is to be.

The input model itself looks like this:

```
public class InputModel
    {

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Full name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Payroll")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Payroll { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public List<String> Roles { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

As below, I currently have hardcoded values on my view (excerpt):

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Input.Roles"></label>
            <select asp-for="Input.Roles" class="form-control">
                <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                <option value="NormalUser" selected>NormalUser</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

This works for what i want it to do, but I would like to replace this with a dynamic list of roles from my application.

I have the following in my OnGet() method

```
var roles = _roleManager.Roles.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
InputModel vm = new InputModel();
vm.Roles = roles;
ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
```

What I'm asking is how to get the list of roles into a shape that I can use on the page itself.

Thanks.

edit... full code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MailTracker.Models;

namespace MailTracker.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
[AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public RegisterModel(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
        IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Full name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Payroll")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Payroll { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public List<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }

        public string SelectedRole { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var roles = _roleManager.Roles.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
        InputModel vm = new InputModel
        {
            RoleList = roles.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList()
        };
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser {
                UserName = Input.Email,
                Email = Input.Email,
                Name = Input.Name,
                Payroll = Input.Payroll
            };

            string role = Input.SelectedRole;

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                //add default NormalUser role to user




                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);

                //

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

}

and the full page itself:

```html
@page
@model RegisterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
            <hr />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Name"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Payroll"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Payroll" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Payroll" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.RoleList"></label>
                <select asp-for="Input.SelectedRole" asp-items="Model.Input.RoleList" class="form-control"></select>
            </div>

            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do these steps to load the list into `<select>` tag helper:

1) Create a `List<SelectListItem>` property in viewmodel (e.g. `InputModel`) and a `string` property to hold selected value.

```
[Required]
public string SelectedRole { get; set; }

public List<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }
```

2) Convert existing `List<string>` property using LINQ `Select` to the `List<SelectListItem>` object and assign it to `RoleList` property.

```
vm.RoleList = vm.Roles.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList();
```

3) Finally, use `asp-items` tag helper to bind it into `<select>` element:

```
<select asp-for="Input.SelectedRole" asp-items="Input.RoleList" class="form-control"></select>
```

**Update:**

As alternative, you can add `List<SelectListItem>` as a `PageModel` property with expression-bodied members:

```
public List<SelectListItem> RoleList => vm.Roles.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList();
```

And set `Model.RoleList` for `asp-items` attribute:

```
<select asp-for="Input.SelectedRole" asp-items="Model.RoleList" class="form-control"></select>
```

If you don't want to add `List<SelectListItem>` property, you can use `ViewData` assigned with options list:

```
ViewData["RoleList"] = vm.Roles.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList();
```

And bind to the page like this:

```
<select asp-for="Input.SelectedRole" asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["RoleList"])"></select>
```

The `<option>` tag will be created automatically, no need to hardcode it anymore.

**Note:** Avoid binding `List<string>` directly to `asp-for` attribute, since `asp-for` for `<select>` tag intended to have single value (i.e. selected value from `<option>` list), also you should remove `RequiredAttribute` for `Roles` property as the attribute is now unnecessary and may trigger model validation error.

Additional reference: [The Select Tag Helper](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/select-tag-helper)

Comment: thanks for coming back: <select asp-for="SelectedRole" asp-items="Model.RoleList" class="form-control"></select> is showing an error in the page. RegisterModel does not contain a definition for RoleList. I fear I may not have included enough information. I have edited my original post to show the full code behind. can you advise please?

Comment: I edited the `<select>` part to satisfy your requirements, also remove `[Required]` attribute above `Roles` property.

Comment: once again, thanks for your input. I did indeed remove the required attribute, and I changed the asp-items to "Input.RoleList". However, now I get the error message "the name Input does not exist in the current context". Do you have any more suggestions, please? Thanks again.

Comment: curiously, Model.Input.RoleList is accepted by intellisense but this causes an error when i visit the Register page - NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Sounds like the model binding doesn't bind `RoleList` when `OnGet()` executed, hence the property may still has null value when `asp-items` callback kicks in. I added alternatives using `PageModel` and `ViewData` to try.

Comment: ok - this worked for me with the ViewData solution. thanks for taking the time. it isn't exactly the solution I was looking for but it certainly solves the problem. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this: `<select asp-for="Role" asp-items="Model.RolesItems"></select>`

```
public List<SelectListItem> RolesItems 
public string Role
```

More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-select-tag-helper)